Нужно напечатать триугольник. С клавиатуры вводится высота и ширина основания треугольника
Я написала код. Но он неправильно работает. Я не понимаю, какой цикл я делаю неправильно. Я думаю, что проблема в том, что в первом цикле я иду  до col а  во втором  до row. Но как по другому сделать, я  не  знаю.
std::cout << "Enter row: ";
int row;
std::cin >> row;

std::cout << "Enter col: ";
int col;
std::cin >> col;
for (int row = 0; row < col; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < row; ++col)
        std::cout << "*";
    std::cout << "\n";
}


row 3
col 4 
*
**
***



Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

1 ) Вы теряете заданное количество строк, поэтому сделайте первый цикл
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)

2 ) Не вполне ясно, как должен выглядеть треугольник - если так, как у вас, прямоугольный с левым вертикальным ребром, то рассчитывайте количество звездочек, например, так:
  for (int j = 0; j < 1 + i*(col-1)/(row-1); ++j)
     std::cout << "*";

Формула выбрана из тех соображений, что в первой строке должна быть одна звездочка, в последней col звездочек, а в остальных - линейная интерполяция между этими величинами.

Я бы добавил, что самая верхняя сирока (нулевая) должна быть из одной *, а самая нижняя ровно из col звездочек. А вот для всех промежуточных (в цикле от 1 до row - 1) количество звездочек нужно рассчитывать

@avp Да, так и есть
